# Sanity Check: RS485 Communications

Tags: rs485

Alright so I am new to RS485 communications I am putting together a document for client to wire up a Atlas Copco Mark V gateway device (Protocol Converter from CAN to Modbus RTU) to a Red Lion Protocol Converter (Modbus RTU to Modbus TCP), I know its a weird setup but its the best option we had. The Modbus RTU connection between the AC Mark V and the Red Lion is over RS485. With little experience in this field and very confusing online resources I want to make sure I have this pinout correct. Alright so here is the
[AC Mark V Pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK2KU.png) and here is the [Red Lion Pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ6Aa.png). How I currently have it set up is Pin 3 on the Mark V (TxD/RxD+) goes to pin 7 on the Red Lion (TxB) and Pin 8 on the Mark V (TxD/RxD-) goes to Pin 8 (TxA) on the Red Lion.

Something isn't working in our communications system and I believe this is where the issue lies. We can communicate between the two systems but data isn't going through like it should be. If anyone can help confirm/deny what I did that would be very helpful. Thank you for your time.